# How to test database failure with Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord

I'm targetting 100% coverage on a fresh new rails application. I only have one resource, auto-generated.

For creation and update operations, the generated source code contains a "else" case, triggered on database failure (save has failed).

```
# POST /projects
# POST /projects.json
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  @project.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

As It's part of my controller (and may include dedicated behavior like redirection or error message), I want to test it in unit test, under MiniTest.

I have a beginning of solution with creating a test containing `ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection`. I also create a teardown function containing the opposite : `ActiveRecord::Base.estabish_connection`

```
test "should not create project" do
  assert_equal('Project.count') do
    ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
    post :create, project: { name: @project.name, user_id: @project.user_id }
  end

  assert_redirected_to projects_path
end
```

And to restore connection for other tests :

```
teardown do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

It's not acceptable for (at least) two reasons :

- the test finishes in a exception ConnectionNotEstablished which is not the goal of the test, and after that I can't verify the behavior of the controler itself (redirection)
- `establish_connection` is performed on every test (useless 90% of time)

Thanks for your suggestions !

EDIT : added code source

Comment: Can you include the code block under test and your attempted test code? It would be helpful to see to make sure we are correctly understanding how your logic works.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to create a mock that short-circuits the save process with a specific return value. (in this case, it would return false to hit your else case). https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/message-expectations

Comment: Yes, it could be the solution ! Thanks for the URL but it's not clear for me how to use this in the case of ActiveRecord action. May you write roughly (untested) some code to give me a leg up ?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I think you want to use a mock instead of disconnecting your database. Since you are using `@project.save` to check if the save worked, we want it to return `false` instead of raising a `ConnectionNotEstablished` error.

We can try to use [MiniTest::Mock](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Mock.html) to accomplish this, but other people might use an external mocking library like [Mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha).

*Note: I don't use minitest, so this is my best guess*

```
test "should not create project" do
  Project.expect(:find, @project) do
    @project.expect(:save, false) do
      assert_equal('Project.count') do
        post :create, project: { name: @project.name, user_id: @project.user_id }
      end
    end
  end

  assert_redirected_to projects_path
end
```

If you use mocha, it might look something like this:

```
test "should not create project" do
  Project.any_instance.stubs(:save).returns(false)
  assert_equal('Project.count') do
    post :create, project: { name: @project.name, user_id: @project.user_id }
  end

  assert_redirected_to projects_path
end
```